# How to customize smart app banner for android in branch.io?

Tags: android, css, wordpress, branch.io, smartbanner

I used the code provided by branch metrics in wordpress to create a smart banner, but I am unable to change the color, height and position of the banner. I also need an arrow on the banner!! Is there a plugin for this purpose in wordpress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: we don't currently have a WordPress plugin for the smart banner, but this is a great idea!

In the meantime, we have a number of [customization options](https://dev.branch.io/features/smart-banner/advanced/#configuration-options) you can use, and you can also apply your own [custom CSS styles](https://dev.branch.io/features/smart-banner/advanced/#styling-the-banner-using-custom-css) to the banner.

**EDIT**

To simply adjust the height of the banner is a bit of a hack that you'll have to feel through for yourself, but you can use this code as a starting point (increases height from 76px to 90px as an example):

```
    <style>
        #branch-banner-iframe {
            height: 90px !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode banner closeBanner creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setIdentity track validateCode".split(" "), 0);
        branch.init('key_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        branch.banner({
            icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wineass/ios7-redesign/512/Appstore-icon.png',
            title: 'Branch Demo App',
            description: 'The Branch demo app!',
                customCSS: '.content { height: 90px !important; } .right { height: 77px !important; padding-top: 29px !important; } .left { height: 77px !important; } #branch-banner-close { top: 21px; } #branch-banner .icon img { margin-top: 7px; }'
        }, {});
    </script>
```

Comment: But the customization options do not provide me the option of resizing my banner. If you can provide a code snippet which i can add to that provided on branch, it would help!